# How do I Reference an Android Library with Resources in Titanium Module

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-modules

I'm writing a Titanium module, and need to reference an Android Library in the project. Setting up the module to include and android libarary reference is [fairly straight forward](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/11/integrating-an-external-library-in-an-android-module/).

All of the documentation and help I can find is for referencing a library by it's .jar file. This is fine when the library being referenced doesn't contain any of it's own external resources (localization strings, images, etc). However, when a library DOES contain it's own resources, Android documentation stipulates that you must [refrence the library project itself](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) instead of just including a reference to the compiled .jar file.

I can't find any documentation on how to setup such a reference in a titanium module. I have been able to get my module to compile by setting up a project reference in the "Java build Path" of my module's properties. However, I get runtime errors as the module tries to access resources from the library project (in my case, localized strings from strings.xml) and they can't be found.

What (if any) is the proper method to configure a Titanium module to use an external Android Library that provides resources?

Answer (score 0):

Your question might be related to this known issue: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-11360

Comment: Thanks for the info Ricardo. This very well may be the issue I am running into. However, the Android library I'm trying to use in my module is the Google Play Services Library, thus I don't have access to the source to implement the workaround (converting the library's xml layouts to java/widgets).

Comment: I suggest you provide this insight in the Jira ticket.  That way you'll be able to know if there's another workaround, this is something that is actually addressed by the fix, if this is possible in any other way, or if there's a need for a separate ticket.

Also, I assume you've already seen this, but here's a repo with a bunch of Appcelerator-developed modules.  Perhaps there's one already doing what you're trying to do: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules